# Net selling price with commission and taxes based on percentage desired

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Say I have listed my house for sale for $100,000 and I would like to net 90% of my asking price.  I have to pay a 2% commission to the buying agent and that commission will be taxed at 13%.  How do I calculate this?  Also how does the calculation change if the full sale price is taxed and not just the 2% commission.

If s is my selling price, a is my original asking price, p is my desired net percentage, c is my commission rate, and t is the tax rate on my commission then I think it should be something like:

s=pa+(cts)

But I don't see how I can reduce this to a reusable equation where I can just plug in the variables and get s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $s$ the selling price. Then the  commission is $cs$. I will assume that seller pays tax on commission, else that tax is irrelevant.

The tax on the commission is $tcs$.  So the total selling costs are $cs+tcs$.

We sold the house for $s$, so the amount of money we have after paying commission and tax is $s-cs-tcs$.  This should be equal to $pa$. We have arrived at the equation
$$pa=s-cs-tcs.$$

We solve this for $s$. Note that the right-hand side is equal to $s(1-c-tc)$. So we are solving the equation
$$s(1-c-tc)=pa.$$
Divide both sides by $1-c-tc$. We conclude that
$$s=\frac{pa}{1-c-tc}.$$

**Note:** The numbers should be expressed in decimal form. If we use the numbers of your example, then $p=0.90$, $c=0.02$, and $t=0.13$. As a check of whether you are inputting numbers into the formula correctly, with the numbers you gave I get a selling price of $92081.03$.

Comment: Beautiful.  Using s*1 to pull s out of the equation was a huge sticking point for me.  For anyone re-reading this pa is percent times asking price so in my example .90 * 100,000.  Thank you for an elegant solution.  I'm sure I can derive the answer to my additional question from this.